# Ingress nginx 404 not-found in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes

I use helm NGINX-INGRESS and NGINX but 404 not-found in browser.

- get ingress information. kubectl get ing -n default

```
NAME            CLASS   HOSTS               ADDRESS          PORTS   AGE
nginx-ingress   nginx   nginx.example.com   104.248.98.230   80      12h
```

- get detail of pod in k8s. kubectl describe pod -n default pod-name

```
Name:         nginx-deployment-76cf68c6b6-6tv5w
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         pool-ducnp-7ir42/10.104.0.3
Start Time:   Mon, 24 Oct 2022 18:43:24 +0700
Labels:       app=nginx-deployment
              pod-template-hash=76cf68c6b6
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.244.0.147
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.0.147
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/nginx-deployment-76cf68c6b6
Containers:
  nginx:
    Container ID:   containerd://f55a8cbae816f2191067f8194c094438cd780b63fa2e6c8fc049f827c58fb201
    Image:          nginx:latest
    Image ID:       docker.io/library/nginx@sha256:5ffb682b98b0362b66754387e86b0cd31a5cb7123e49e7f6f6617690900d20b2
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Mon, 24 Oct 2022 18:43:28 +0700
    
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-bfgxb:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Events:                      <none>
```

- get detail of ingress k8s. kubectl describe ing -n default nginx-ingress

```
Name:             nginx-ingress
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        default
Address:          104.248.98.230
Ingress Class:    nginx
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host               Path  Backends
  ----               ----  --------
  nginx.example.com  
                     /   nginx-service:80 (10.244.0.147:80)
Annotations:         <none>
Events:              <none>
```

- get detail of service in k8s. kubectl describe svc nginx-ingress

```
Name:                     nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress
Namespace:                default
Selector:                 app=nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.245.0.15
IPs:                      10.245.0.15
LoadBalancer Ingress:     104.248.98.230
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 http  31162/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.0.203:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               443/TCP
NodePort:                 https  30194/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.0.203:443
Session Affinity:         None
```

- somebody have the same issue, please help me

Answer (score 0):

I fixed when use minikube, with cmd

```
minikube tunnel
```